# PowerBI consuming Data Bricks consuming Azure Data Lake GEN1

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I am trying to consume Azure Data Bricks from Power BI. 
Bricks has been set up to connect to Azure DataLake GEN1.

I have no issue in getting data out of GEN1 from Bricks.
And I have no issue in consuming a Bricks instance from Power BI.

However, when trying the whole chain, Power BI consuming Bricks and Bricks calling into GEN1, I get a security related error saying that is not possible to find ADLS Gen1 Token in com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.adl.AdlCredentialContextTokenProvider.

Do you have any idea of what the problem that I am facing could be?

Cheers,
G.